# Rails: are static error pages (500.html, 404.html) rendered without any setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am debugging a application and i see one setting as

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

in config/environments/staging.rb and a 500.html file in public directory.

So if the status in header is 500, does rails display 500.html automatically? or do i need to make additional settings so that if exception occurs display 500.html

i am using rails 3.1, any help on this will be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

> **14.1 The Default 500 and 404 Templates**
>
> By default a production application will render either a 404 or a 500 error message. These messages are contained in static HTML files in the public folder, in 404.html and 500.html respectively. You can customize these files to add some extra information and layout, but remember that they are static; i.e. you can't use RHTML or layouts in them, just plain HTML.

[Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-default-500-and-404-templates)

Comment: this makes sense, i have upvoted it, but can you provide me some official docuementation so that i can accept your answer

Comment: @opensource-ios well, now there isn't a problem with 'too short answer body'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it automatically loads the static html files public/500.html and public/404.html.

Being static files, these do not go through the usual Rails pipeline.

For other message codes, or if you want to customize your error messages with advanced stuff like Ruby code and/or database access, you need to do the following:

- Add the necessary routes;
- Create an `ErrorsController` with it's correspondent actions and views.

---

```
# config/routes.rb
get "500", to "errors#error_500", code: "500"

# app/controllers/ErrorsController.rb
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def error_500
  end
end
```

Comment: I dont see an errorscontroller in my current application and nither the route you suggested but still loading the public/500.html when exception occurs, thats why i am wondering if rails does it automatically

Comment: @MihaiAndreiDinculescu, nope, it does.

Comment: I didn't know that it loads that automatically, but now that you mention it, it kinda makes sense :)

Comment: You're still stuck to plain HTML and only for 404 and 500. So you still might end up customizing them.